# I'm rotating an object on two axes, so why does it keep twisting around the third axis?

Tags: rotation, geometry, transformation

I see questions come up quite often that have this underlying issue, but they're all caught up in the particulars of a given feature or tool. Here's an attempt to create a canonical answer we can refer users to when this comes up - with lots of animated examples! :)

---

Let's say we're making a first-person camera. The basic idea is it should yaw to look left & right, and pitch to look up & down. So we write a bit of code like this (using Unity as an example):

```
void Update() {
    float speed = lookSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Yaw around the y axis using the player's horizontal input.        
    transform.Rotate(0f, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, 0f);

    // Pitch around the x axis using the player's vertical input.
    transform.Rotate(-Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed,  0f, 0f);
}
```

or maybe

```
// Construct a quaternion or a matrix representing incremental camera rotation.
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(
                        -Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed,
                         Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed,
                         0);

// Fold this change into the camera's current rotation.
transform.rotation *= rotation;
```

And it mostly works, but over time the view starts to get crooked. The camera seems to be turning on its roll axis (z) even though we only told it to rotate on the x and y!

[image: Animated example of a first-person camera tilting sideways]

This can also happen if we're trying to manipulate an object in front of the camera - say it's a globe we want to turn to look around:

[image: Animated example of a globe tilting sideways]

The same problem - after a while the North pole starts to wander away to the left or right. We're giving input on two axes but we're getting this confusing rotation on a third. And it happens whether we apply all our rotations around the object's local axes or the world's global axes.

In many engines you'll also see this in the inspector - rotate the object in the world, and suddenly numbers change on an axis we didn't even touch!

[image: Animated example showing manipulating an object next to a readout of its rotation angles. The z angle changes even though the user didn't manipulate that axis.]

**So, is this an engine bug?** How do we tell the program we don't want it adding extra rotation?

Does it have something to do with Euler angles? Should I use Quaternions or Rotation Matrices or Basis Vectors instead?

Comment: [See also a previous treatment of this topic here, featuring multiple solutions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/30644/39518)

Comment: I found the answer to the following question very helpful also. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/123535/unwanted-roll-when-rotating-camera-with-pitch-and-yaw

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**No this isn't an engine bug or an artifact** of a particular rotation representation (those can happen too, but this effect applies to every system that represents rotations, quaternions included).

You've discovered a real fact about how rotation works in three-dimensional space, and it departs from our intuition about other transformations like translation:

[image: Animated example showing that applying rotations in a different order gives different results]

When we compose rotations on more than one axis, the result we get isn't just the total/net value we applied to each axis (as we might expect for translation). The order in which we apply the rotations changes the result, as each rotation moves the axes on which the next rotations get applied (if rotating about the object's local axes), or the relationship between the object and the axis (if rotating about the world's axes).

The changing of axis relationships over time can confuse our intuition about what each axis is "supposed" to do. In particular, certain combinations of yaw and pitch rotations give the same result as a roll rotation!

[image: Animated example showing a sequence of local pitch-yaw-pitch gives the same output as a single local roll]

You can verify that each step is rotating correctly about the axis we requested - there's no engine glitch or artifact in our notation interfering with or second-guessing our input - the spherical (or hyperspherical / quaternion) nature of rotation just means our transformations "wrap around" onto each other. They may be orthogonal locally, for small rotations, but as they pile up we find they're not globally orthogonal.

This is most dramatic and clear for 90-degree turns like those above, but the wandering axes creep in over many small rotations too, as demonstrated in the question.

### So, what do we do about it?

If you already have a pitch-yaw rotation system, one of the quickest ways to eliminate unwanted roll is to change one of the rotations to operate on the global or parent transformation axes instead of the object's local axes. That way you can't get cross-contamination between the two - one axis remains absolutely controlled.

Here's the same sequence of pitch-yaw-pitch that became a roll in the example above, but now we apply our yaw around the global Y axis instead of the object's

[image: Animated example of a mug rotating with local pitch and global yaw, with no roll problem][image: Animated example of first-person camera using global yaw]

So we can fix the first-person camera with the mantra "Pitch Locally, Yaw Globally":

```
void Update() {
    float speed = lookSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    transform.Rotate(0f, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, 0f, Space.World);
    transform.Rotate(-Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed,  0f, 0f, Space.Self);
}
```

If you're compounding your rotations using multiplication, you'd flip the left/right order of one of the multiplications to get the same effect:

```
// Yaw happens "over" the current rotation, in global coordinates.
Quaternion yaw = Quaternion.Euler(0f, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, 0f);
transform.rotation =  yaw * transform.rotation; // yaw on the left.

// Pitch happens "under" the current rotation, in local coordinates.
Quaternion pitch = Quaternion.Euler(-Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed, 0f, 0f);
transform.rotation = transform.rotation * pitch; // pitch on the right.
```

(The specific order will depend on the multiplication conventions in your environment, but left = more global / right = more local is a common choice)

This is equivalent to storing up the net total yaw and total pitch you want as float variables, then always applying the net result all at once, constructing a single new orientation quaternion or matrix from these angles alone (provided you keep `totalPitch` clamped):

```
// Construct a new orientation quaternion or matrix from Euler/Tait-Bryan angles.
var newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(totalPitch, totalYaw, 0f);
// Apply it to our object.
transform.rotation = newRotation;
```

or equivalently...

```
// Form a view vector using total pitch & yaw as spherical coordinates.
Vector3 forward = new Vector3(
                    Mathf.cos(totalPitch) * Mathf.sin(totalYaw),
                    Mathf.sin(totalPitch),
                    Mathf.cos(totalPitch) * Mathf.cos(totalYaw));

// Construct an orientation or view matrix pointing in that direction.
var newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forward, new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
// Apply it to our object.
transform.rotation = newRotation;
```

Using this global/local split, the rotations don't have a chance to compound and influence each other, because they're applied to independent sets of axes.

The same idea can help if it's an object in the world that we want to rotate. For an example like the globe, we'd often want to invert it and apply our yaw locally (so it always spins around its poles) and pitch globally (so it tips toward/away from our view, rather than toward/away from Australia, wherever it's pointing...)

[image: Animated example of a globe showing better-behaved rotation]

### Limitations

This global/local hybrid strategy isn't always the right fix. For example, in a game with 3D flight/swimming, you might want to be able to point straight up / straight down and still have full control. But with this setup you'll hit [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) - your yaw axis (global up) becomes parallel to your roll axis (local forward), and you have no way to look left or right without twisting.

What you can do instead in cases like this is to use pure local rotations like we started with in the question above (so your controls feel the same no matter where you're looking), which will initially let some roll creep in - but then we correct for it.

For example, we can use local rotations to update our "forward" vector, then use that forward vector together with a reference "up" vector to construct our final orientation. (Using, for example, Unity's [Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) method, or manually constructing an orthonormal matrix from these vectors) By controlling the up vector, we control the roll or twist.

For the flight/swimming example, you'll want to apply these corrections gradually over time. If it's too abrupt, the view can lurch in a distracting way. Instead, you can use the player's current up vector and hint it toward the vertical, frame-by-frame, until their view levels out. Applying this during a turn can sometimes be less nauseating than twisting the camera while the player's controls are idle.

Comment: May I ask how you made to gifs? They look nice.

Comment: @Bálint I use a free program called [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) — it lets you record a portion of your screen into a gif. Then I trim the animation / add additional caption text / compress the gif using Photoshop.

Comment: Is this answer for Unity only? Is there a more generic answer on the Web?

Comment: @posfan12 The example code uses Unity syntax for concreteness, but the situations and math involved apply equally across the board. Are you having any difficulty applying the examples to your environment?

Comment: Yes, I am not using Unity so I would benefit from the actual maths involved. See https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/149736/first-person-style-controls for my specific problem. Thanks.

Comment: Should I post a new question?

Comment: The math is already present above. Judging by your edit, you're just mashing up the wrong parts of it. It looks like you're using the [vector type defined here](https://github.com/HazenBabcock/LDView/blob/master/LDView/TCFoundation/TCVector.cpp). This includes a method to construct a rotation matrix from a set of angles as described above. Start with an identity matrix and call `TCVector::calcRotationMatrix(totalPitch, totalYaw, identity)` - this is equivalent to the "all at once Euler" example above.

Comment: Does the `calcRotationMatrix` function return a matrix? I don't know of a method of `camera` that accepts a matrix. For instance, `camera.rotate` only accepts three angles as input. (The GitHub you linked to is the program I'm trying to modify.)

Comment: Dissecting your source code is probably not a great use of the comments here. ;) Want to try [chat]?

Answer (score 2):

AFTER 16 hours of parenting and rotation functions lol.

I just wanted to have code have an empty, basically, turning in circles and also front flipping as it turns.

Or in other words, the goal is to rotate yaw and pitch without any effect on roll.

**Here are the few that actually worked in my application**

In Unity:

1. Create an empty. Call it ForYaw.
2. Give that a child empty, called ForPitch.
3. Finally, make a cube and move it to z= 5 (forward). Now we can see what we are trying to avoid, which will be twisting the cube *(accidental "roll" while we yaw and pitch)*.

Now scripting in Visual Studio, do your setup, and end up with this in Update:

```
objectForYaw.Rotate(objectForYaw.up, 1f, Space.World);
    objectForPitch.Rotate(objectForPitch.right, 3f, Space.World);

    //this will work on the pitch object as well
    //objectForPitch.RotateAround
    //    (objectForPitch.position, objectForPitch.right, 3f);
```

Note that it all broke for me when I tried to vary the order of parenting. Or if I change Space.World for the *child pitch* object (the parent Yaw doesn't mind being rotated through Space.Self). Confusing. I could definitely use some clarification on why I had to take a local axis but apply it through world space — why does Space.Self ruin everything?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether this is intended to answer the question, or if you're asking for help understanding why the code you've written works this way. If it's the latter, you should post a new question, linking to this page for context if you like. As a hint, `me.Rotate(me.right, angle, Space.World)` is the same as `me.Rotate(Vector3.right, angle, Space.Self`, and your nested transforms are equivalent to the "Pitch Locally, Yaw Globally" examples in the accepted answer.

Comment: A little of both. Partly to share in the answer (e.g. here is exactly how it worked for me). And also to introduce the question.

That hint has got me thinking. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Amazing this wasn't upvoted. After hours reading comprehensive answers which although educational still didn't work, the simple answer of using the objects rotation axis instead of a generic Vector3.right axis is all it took to keep rotation fixed on the object. Incredible what I was looking for was buried here with 0 votes and on the 2nd page of Google of many, many similar questions.