# Transform values stay zero while catching mouse movement

Tags: unity, c#, transformation, lerp

I am working on a game using GoogleVR, but I don't think that has anything to do with my problem.

Basically, I am testing to see if I can move a stick by using the mouse at the moment.

I am getting mouse movement, as seen from the value of `md`:

```
(-0.5,-1.25)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerMovement:Update() (at Assets/Character Pack/PlayerMovement.cs:30)
```

But the transform is wrong, as seen from the `localRotation`:

```
(0,0,0)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerMovement:Update() (at Assets/Character Pack/PlayerMovement.cs:29)
```

I just want to see my stick move in some predictable way based on the movement of the mouse, and I am not certain why my equation is wrong.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector2 mouseLook;
    Vector2 smoothV;
    public float sensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float smoothing = 2.0f;

    public GameObject stick;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        smoothV.x = 0.5f;
        smoothV.y = 0.5f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        var md = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw ("Mouse Y"));

        md = Vector2.Scale(md, new Vector2(sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
        smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp (smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
        smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp (smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);

        stick.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
        stick.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (mouseLook.x, stick.transform.up);
        Debug.Log ("(" + stick.transform.localRotation.x + "," + stick.transform.localRotation.y + "," + stick.transform.localRotation.z + ")");
        Debug.Log ("(" + md.x + "," + md.y + ")");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes in this code, which makes it a bit difficult to sort out what's the root problem you're trying to solve versus what's noise.

Firstly, you're storing your mouse movement in `md`, and debugging its contents to make sure it got set properly, but not using it at all for rotation. Your rotation code is using a completely different variable `mouselook` which so far as I can tell you never populate with any non-zero values.

Then your rotation code sets `localRotation` with your pitch rotation... then immediately overwrites this with a yaw rotation, so the first line setting `localRotation` might as well not be there — the very next line replaces whatever it tried to do. Did you mean to combine these two partial rotations using multiplication or `Quaternion.Euler`?

Your rotation debug only looks at the x, y, and z components of the `localRotation` quaternion, which won't be very informative. These components hold the axis of rotation, scaled by the sine of half the angle — which is very nearly zero for small angles. To get a more intelligible human-readable value, you might want to check `transform.localEulerAngles` instead.

Lastly, you need to be a bit careful when rotating on two axes in sequence, as [this can produce unexpected results](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136174/39518) based on the order of composition.

Comment: Thank you. I missed mouseLook, but more importantly you were correct that it was horribly wrong.  Here is what I am happy with, just to show that it will move.  It isn't perfect but it achieves the goal. stick.transform.Rotate(45 * (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime), 
   0, 45 * (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime));