# First-person shooter -style controls

Tags: camera, rotation, first-person-shooter

This is not in regard to a video game, but to a 3D model viewer someone else created and I am modifying.

I would like to implement first-person -style mouse and keyboard controls in the viewer, so that you can navigate through the model as if it were a house or building.

Right now, when you move the mouse up, down, left or right, the rotations are relative to the camera's coordinate axes. Which means over time you can end up with some really weird camera positions.

How do I change this to FPS-style rotations where (I think) you use latitude/longitude rotations, and the "up" direction is always perpendicular to the ground plane.

Is there a simple conversion formula I can use on the mouse input? Thanks!

(BTW, I've already implemented correct lateral camera translation. The only issue remaining is the camera rotation.)

[edit]

The article below describes my problem well, but does not provide a solution I can use since I am not using Unity.

[I'm rotating an object on two axes, so why does it keep twisting around the third axis?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136174/im-rotating-an-object-on-two-axes-so-why-does-it-keep-twisting-around-the-thir)

[edit]

Here is the function I am trying to edit. Most of it is not relevant, but you can browse through it to see what's going on. The only part I really want to change is the line with the comment "fix rotations here!!".

```
void LDrawModelViewer::updateCameraPosition(void)
{
    float multiplier = 100.0f;
    float factor = 1.0f / multiplier;
    TCFloat motionAmount = 20.0f * (TCFloat)sqrt(fov / 45.0f);
    /*
    if (modifierKeys & MKShift)
    {
        motionAmount *= 2.0f;
        strafeAmount *= 2.0f;
        rotationAmount *= 2.0f;
        rollAmount *= 2.0f;
    }
    */
#ifdef WIN32
    if (hrpcFrequency.QuadPart != 0)
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER newCount;

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&newCount);
        factor = (float)((newCount.QuadPart - hrpcFrameCount.QuadPart) /
            (double)hrpcFrequency.QuadPart);
    }
    else
    {
        factor = (GetTickCount() - frameTicks) / 1000.0f;
    }
#endif // WIN32
#ifdef _QT
    factor = qtime.elapsed() /1000.0f;
#endif
#ifdef COCOA
    if (FRAME_TIME != nil)
    {
        factor = (float)-[FRAME_TIME timeIntervalSinceNow];
    }
#endif // COCOA
    if (viewMode == VMFlyThrough && flyMode == FMUpSide)
    {
        TCVector upVector(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        TCVector tempMotion(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        TCFloat matrix[16];
        TCFloat inverseMatrix[16];
        TCVector::invertMatrix(camera.getFacing().getMatrix(), inverseMatrix);
        TCVector::multMatrix(inverseMatrix, rotationMatrix, matrix);
        TCVector tempVector = upVector.transformNormal(matrix);
        if (cameraMotion[2] > 0.0f)
        {
            tempMotion[1] += -tempVector[2];
            tempMotion[2] += tempVector[1];
        }
        else if (cameraMotion[2] < 0.0f)
        {
            tempMotion[1] += tempVector[2];
            tempMotion[2] += -tempVector[1];
        }
        if (cameraMotion[1] > 0.0f)
        {
            tempMotion[1] += (1 - tempVector[2]);
            tempMotion[2] += (1 - tempVector[1]);
        }
        else if (cameraMotion[1] < 0.0f)
        {
            tempMotion[1] += -(1 - tempVector[2]);
            tempMotion[2] += -(1 - tempVector[1]);
        }
        tempMotion[0] = cameraMotion[0];
        camera.move(tempMotion * motionAmount * factor * multiplier);
        // fix rotations here!!
        camera.rotate(TCVector(cameraXRotate, cameraYRotate, cameraZRotate) *
            factor * multiplier * 1.5f);
    }
    else
    {
        //camera.move(cameraMotion * size / 100.0f * factor * multiplier);
        camera.move(cameraMotion * motionAmount * factor * multiplier);
        camera.rotate(TCVector(cameraXRotate, cameraYRotate, cameraZRotate) *
            factor * multiplier * 1.5f);
    }
}
```

[edit]

<s>On a hunch, I changed that line to this:</s>

```
    // Form a view vector using total pitch & yaw as spherical coordinates.
    TCVector globeVector
    (
        cos(cameraXRotate) * sin(cameraYRotate),
        sin(cameraXRotate),
        cos(cameraXRotate) * cos(cameraYRotate)
    );
    camera.rotate(globeVector * factor * multiplier * 1.5f);
```

But this did not have the desired effect.

[edit]

<s>Okay, I replaced the previous code with:</s>

```
    TCFloat identity[16];
    memcpy(identity, TCVector::sm_identityMatrix, sizeof(TCVector::sm_identityMatrix));
    TCVector::calcRotationMatrix(cameraXRotate, cameraYRotate, identity);
```

But I get an error that `TCVector::sm_identityMatrix` is inaccessible.

Also, how do I feed the new matrix back to the camera? The `camera.rotate` method only takes a three component vector as input AFAIK. I was unable to locate any documentation on the `camera` object, and the code has few comments in it.

Comment: Matrix/quaternion math isn't Unity specific. You just need to use your versions of the functions that are used in the answer to the post marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I am not using an external library and need to implement this from scratch.

Comment: What language are you using and why are you not using external libraries? If it's a 3d app, presumably there are already matrices and quaternions somewhere in there.

Comment: So implement matrix & quaternion math then? There's no getting around those really if you're working in 3D.

Comment: C++. As I said, I did not create the program, and I'm not going to rewrite the whole thing just for one small change.

Comment: Your `TCVector` type already includes the methods you need to solve this, [if it's the one I found here](https://github.com/HazenBabcock/LDView/blob/master/LDView/TCFoundation/TCVector.cpp). The main methods you need are the ones that create an identity matrix (so you have a clean starting point) and `calcRotationMatrix` which already does all the work of rotating a matrix in the latitude-longitude way described in the answer to the linked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me! :) I've updated the question with my latest attempt.

Comment: And, yes, you actually found the program I'm trying to modify. :)

Comment: Your edits have changed the topic of the question from "how do I get rid of unintuitive camera movement in an FPS style control scheme" to "How do I syntactically work with this particular camera API" which is a different question entirely, and one which we can't answer solely with the information presented here. It might be a better topic to work through in chat, as it's less likely to fit in a neat Q&A that will be useful to future users.

Comment: I will be home from work in 7 hours. Will you be online then? Does SE support pings or private messages?

Comment: There's a good chance I'll be around. I don't know a good way to send someone a push notification within the site, but you can [DM me on Twitter](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory) if I'm not in the main [chat] room.

Comment: Using the @ with the user's name in a message, with the user having the StackExchange app installed on their mobile phone is the best way to ping someone IMHO :) (@DMGregory) There are no way to chat privately (unless you are a mod), but you can create a [new room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) for a specific topic if needed. You can also, from a room where the user is (such as [game dev main room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development)) click on the user's name then click on _start a new room with this user_.

Answer (score -1):

You need a conversion matrix from world space to local space. So you can rotate the camera from the clients view (local space).

Comment: Don't you mean the opposite? I mean, I want to rotate along lat/long aligned with world space.

Comment: Never mind. You are, in fact, absolutely correct.

Comment: I can no longer upvote this answer.

Comment: Why you want to upvote it?

Comment: I actually want to remove the downvote because you were correct.

Comment: Just mark it as the answer if it helped you to solve your problem.

Comment: If not, then just leave it, I'm used to downvotes on correct things x) It's stackexchange