# SuperBible Skybox

Tags: opengl, skybox

I'm reading the SuperBible book which describe and interesting way of rendering a skybox. 
The Idea is to render only a plane, instead of a cube, and only change the texture coordinates depending on the Rotation of the view matrix.

However, the rotation is not correct for me, if Yaw and pitch works at startup, it then roll if I combine them.

The camera seems correct as my models does render correctly (without rolling)

Here is the code:

```
// -----------------------
// OpenGL Calls
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glUseProgram(p.program);
glBindVertexArray(emptyVAO);

glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrixUniform, 1, GL_FALSE,
           glm::value_ptr(frame.View));
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glUniform1i(textureCubeUniform, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureCubeMap);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);


// ------------------------
// Vertex Shader
out vec3 textureCoordinate;

uniform mat4 ViewMatrix;

void
main(void)
{
  vec3[4] vertices = vec3[4](vec3(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0), vec3(1.0, -1.0, 1.0),
                             vec3(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0), vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));

  textureCoordinate = mat3(ViewMatrix) * vertices[gl_VertexID];
  gl_Position = vec4(vertices[gl_VertexID], 1.0);
}

// ------------------------
// Fragment Shader
uniform samplerCube textureCube;

in vec3 textureCoordinate;

out vec4 color;

void main(void)
{
  color = texture(textureCube, textureCoordinate);
}
```

Edit: Here is the Code of the camera

```
yaw += offset.x * speed * deltaTime;
pitch += offset.y * speed * deltaTime;
if (pitch > 89.0f) pitch  = 89.0f;
if (pitch < -89.0f) pitch = -89.0f;

glm::vec3 direction;
direction.x = cos(glm::radians(pitch)) * cos(glm::radians(yaw));
direction.y = sin(glm::radians(pitch));
direction.z = cos(glm::radians(pitch)) * sin(glm::radians(yaw));
direction   = glm::normalize(direction);


View =
  glm::lookAt(position, position + direction, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
```

Comment: [Combining yaw and pitch repeatedly and getting roll at the end is actually totally normal](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136174/39518) so I don't think this is a bug in your shader code. It's more likely in the code that tallies your rotation angles and generates the matrix that you provide as input to the shader. Can you show us that code?

Comment: The camera is a simple Freecam (I added the source code). However, the odd is that, the world is displayed correctly. And the camera does not appears to roll.

Comment: Are you passing the same matrix to the skybox and the rest of the scene rendering? The skybox shader looks like it's expecting an inverse matrix, to go from clip space back to worldspace (the reverse of what your camera view projection matrix does)