# Unity: Particle System start rotation completely incorrect when set via C# script

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, quaternion, particles

I am trying to set the starting rotation of a particle system via c# script so that the particles orientate with another object in the scene. My particle system 3d rotation is set as follows:

```
void UpdateParticleSystemRotation(Quaternion rotation)
    {
        if(this.gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>() != null)
        {
            var particleSystemMainModule = gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().main;
            particleSystemMainModule.startRotationX = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve(rotation.eulerAngles.x);
            particleSystemMainModule.startRotationY = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve(rotation.eulerAngles.y);
            particleSystemMainModule.startRotationZ = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve(rotation.eulerAngles.z);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("There was an error");
        }
    }
```

The rotation.eulerAngles.x/y/z values are coming through correctly, and by debugging in VS I can see that the values have been correctly assigned, as below:

[image: Correctly assigning rotation.eulerAngles.x with the value of the rotation provided in the Quaternion parameter]

However I observe that the particle system is not at all orientated with this X value, and the particle system is showing a completely different value:

[image: Completely incorrect value observed in the editor and orientation of particle system]

You can see from the screenshots above that a **value of 74.5f becomes 4274.2f** by the time it hits the particle system.

I have double checked that the type expected by the ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve constructor is a float. I cannot understand why this is happening.

I would be very grateful if someone would be able to provide some clarification on this.

Many thanks in advance.

---

I should add, rotation seems completely random for any given input value, it doesn't follow any obvious rhyme or rhythm.

I am using Unity 2017.2.0f3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, don't forget to [read the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MainModule-startRotationX.html):

> public ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve startRotationX;
>
> The initial rotation of particles around the X axis when emitted.
>
> **Note that the value should be given in radians**

So 74.5 radians converted to degrees for display in the editor is:

74.5 • 180° / π = 4268.5°

Which looks on par with what you're seeing in the inspector.

Dropping the scale of all your code-provided angles to a few multiples of π should make things behave much more sensibly.

Also remember that order matters when composing rotations, like the x, y, and z angles in Euler form, so take this into account when planning the angles you use to [avoid surprises](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136174/39518).

Comment: Ah! @DMGregory I think you might be onto something there...!! I got confused with the fact that the editor shows in degrees. I shall confirm this is correct when I get home tonight and accept your answer. Thank you kindly for your reply.

Comment: Please do not cross-post between StackExchange sites. We close questions when we spot that they've been cross-posted. Ask on just one site, whichever one you think is best suited to your problem.