# Why does this order of Quaternion multiplication not introduce roll into my fps-style character controller?

Tags: opengl, mathematics, camera, quaternion, opentk

I'm working on an OpenGL based project (in C#), employing Quaternions to rotate my camera I first tried to:

```
cameraOrientation = cameraOrientation * framePitch * frameYaw;
```

This accumulated an undesired roll in my cam-controller which made rotations unusable.
I found a post on stack exchange which suggested this reordering of operations:

```
cameraOrientation = framePitch * cameraOrientation * frameYaw;
```

Which completely solved this accumulation of roll. While I'm comfortable with matrix multiplication, I can't seem to understand *why* this removes roll accumulation. Does anybody have any articles or images so I can grok what's happening here?

It feels weird not to understand such a fundamental operation in my project.
Thanks!

Comment: [Is this the StackExchange post you mentioned](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136174/39518)? I show some animated gif examples to try to explain this effect, which may help you if that's not the original source you used.

Comment: I hadn't seen that post but it helps a lot, thanks. So from my understanding the rearranging makes the pitch dependent on a global orientation instead of the camera's or the yaw's?