# Weird corkscrew rotation on my fps controller

Tags: unity, character-controller

I recently started work on a new game and was making a first person controller. However, this problem came up.

My problem

I played around with it and followed multiple tutorials, but none worked.
[image]

This is my script:

[image: Sry i used visual scripting]
Sry i used visual scripting

Any suggestions?

Comment: [I wrote a thread explaining why you get this rolling twist when repeatedly modifying pitch and yaw](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136174/39518) — does that give you some ideas for how to fix it?

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly!

Comment: Want to add an answer below, showing how you solved this in your visual scripting setup, ot should we close this question as a duplicate of the earlier one?

Comment: I would also reccomend you do learn to code, visual scripting is good, but coding is a lot quicker and probably a bit more powerful in terms of what you can do